# which function should i use in the select output 5 in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Hi i'm new in AnyLogic world. I'm trying to simulate the cereal bar process, now I insert select output 5 in my flowchart because I have 4 different type of bar, but now I don't understand which function I should use for saying to my process what type of bar it must do. In addition, I have an excel file with the production schedule of the bars. I attach the photos of the flowchart and excel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Viviana, welcome to the AnyLogic world. For this question, you first need to tell us how bars actually decide on which process flow to follow. Else we cannot help. Also, read this article to understand the community better: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making use of a combine I would suggest that you set up the combined block to create a new agent of type "Bar" and in Bar, you need to have a variable indicating what bar it is. it is best to make use of an options list  or enumerator, but you can use an integer or string as needed.

[image]

I currently set the value randomly using `BarType.random(getDefaultRandomGenerator())`

[image]

Set Bar as the new agent that gets created at the combine block

[image]

Then in the select output block you can divert bars to go where you want to go

[image]

Comment: in this way the model give me error

Comment: My answer is an example of how you should do it. Apple what I have done to your model in a way that is applicable to your model. If you try and then it throws a new error that you can resolve. Feel free to post a new question. But don't just copy and paste ;-)

Comment: Apple what ^ he said .. Samsung it .. or even Sony it .. but make sure to apply what you learned.